# clone repo from local to remote with windows local

Tags: git, git-clone

I want just to clone my local repository to remote.
My local system is windows where remote is linux.
I made repo on local system with commands like :

```
git init
git remote add origin ssh://user@example.com:22/home/example.git
git add -A
git commit -m "initial upload"
git pull origin master
```

and on remote serve at home direcotry, I ma trying to write like,

```
git clone d:/wamp/www/example_site example.com
```

but it gives error like,

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname d: Name or service not known
```

when i write

```
git clone 192.168.0.100:d/wamp/www/example_site example.com
```

it responds

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.100 port 22: Connection timed out
```

Remember my local system is windows.

I followed this tutorial. [Setup Git Repository On Remote Server And Local machine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6mYtJu0E47U)

I am new to git and already tried many ways but can't find luck. Please help.

Comment: Your repo on the remote host needs to be accessible by GIT in some way. This can be HTTP, HTTPS, SSH or GITs own protocol. If you don't provide a protocol in the URL when cloning, GIT assumes SSH. The "Connection timed out" means that your remote host has no SSH server running. I suggest you install a simple HTTP server and make sure the repo is accessible through it (you can check that in a browser).

Comment: Try ping first.

Comment: @Y.N - It gives Pinging 192.168.0.100 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.0.100: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.0.100: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.0.100: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.0.100: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 192.168.0.100:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak - I did first  ssh user@example.com
and it was connected successfully.

Comment: Then use that user@example.com in your clone line: `git clone user@example.com/d/wamp/www/example_site`